# I wan to be able to run Flutter on an android phone and emulator

Tags: java, flutter, gradle, android-emulator

I am a beginner at Flutter (please forgive me if i don't give details about the problem).
It displays the below error when I try to run flutter on an emulator and my android device. Can someone please help me fix it?
[image]

Comment: Can you post some of the code that caused this error?

Answer (score 1):

You need to accept the licenes from Android to run the app:

run: `flutter doctor --android-licenses`

And accept the terms on the terminal